# how to update column of table by each element of array one by one?

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, string, controller

I want to update table's column

```
$update = DB::table('users')->where('latehours' , '');

foreach($update as $up) {
    $up->update([
        'latehours' => $total_hours
    ]);
}
```

[image]

Comment: `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` is not iteratable. Do you mean `DB::table('users')->where('latehours' , '')->get()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can update your table directly without fetching data from DB:

```
$updated = DB::table('users')->where('latehours', '')
                             ->update(['latehours' => $total_hours]);
```